# SharePoint Online list view web part is showing all items view instead of the view I selected in the editing pane

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, modern-pages

I need to track if specific documents have been created or found. I created a List with the documents we need along with a Yes/No dropdown to indicate if the document has been uploaded to SharePoint.  I created a few views (All documents grouped by type, Uploaded to SharePoint = Yes, Uploaded to SharePoint = No).  I also added a site page for my coworkers to use. On the site page I added three list view web parts and selected the three custom views respectively in each edit web part pane. I pressed apply for all the web parts and they are displaying properly on my computer in both Edge and Chrome.  When I sent the link for the page to my coworker (who has read-only access to the page and contribute access to the list) she can see the three web parts but they are all displaying the All Items default view.  How do I fix this?  What is wrong??

The webparts are set to:
Autosize,
Hide Command Bar,
Hide See All Button,
Dynamic Filtering is Off

Answer (score 0):

I tried to set up a page replicating what you described, and it seems to work ok for me.

One thing that might be a clue is that your coworker only has read only access to the page. If you originally set up the page with the three web parts all pointing to the All Items view, and then modified the page without republishing, then she will only see the previously published version.

In short, have you ensured that your page is in a published state?

Comment: Yes I confirmed the page was published and checked again on a coworker's computer and all of her views showed the All Items view.  She navigated to the page on her own so it's not a link issue.

Comment: Weird... Couple of things I would try to help troubleshoot, would be to create another page with the same setup and see if you get the same behavior. Also see if the same is observed with a different coworker.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your situation exactly, but again, I'm displaying it intact here.
You can try the following to troubleshoot the problem:

1. Make sure your List is fine first, try showing different views of other lists in the page to see if the problem persists.
2. If the problem still exists, then try creating a new page and adding the List web part to see if the problem still exists.
3. You can ask other people who have the same access as your colleague to view the page and see if the problem still exists.
4. Test in other sites to see if the problem persists.
5. Try to use a different browser or your browser's InPrivate mode to see if the same problem occurs.